# How do I create an inputAccessoryView using Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want to create an inputAccessoryView for a UITextView programmatically using Auto Layout. If I create a view and constrain its width and height alone, it appears centered over the top edge of the keyboard instead of above it as I would expect. How can I constrain the bottom edge to equal the top edge of the keyboard?

Comment: Did you set the complete view you want as the inputAccessoryView, or only part of it? Could you also show some code/screenshots of how exactly you achieved this? It might give some insight in what went wrong.